# How to make apache execute script and use output as variable in httpd-ssl.conf

Tags: apache, shell, variables, set

I have **apache 2.4** running on RedHat 7.x.

In **https** Virtualhost section

```
...

<VirtualHost _default_:8082>

DocumentRoot "/some/location/httpd2_4_27/htdocs"
ServerName some_url:8082
...
...

# RewriteMap elastic_cookies "prg:/some/location/get_cookies.sh"
# SetEnv ELASTIC5 %{elastic_cookies}e


SetEnv ELASTIC5 "some_long_cookie_string"

RequestHeader set Cookie "SSOLogin=badcookie; SSOCookie=%{ELASTIC5}e"

ProxyPass / https://my.web/o/rest/user
ProxyPassReverse / https://my.web/o/rest/user

</VirtualHost>
```

However when i make a call on my webserver I want to be able to execute
**shell script** which would make a call for **cookies** basically it would provide a **some_long_cookie_string** dynamically.

When it is hard coded it works.

```
SetEnv ELASTIC5 "some_long_cookie_string"
```

What I need is something like this in my opinion but it is not working:

```
# RewriteMap elastic_cookies "prg:/some/location/get_cookies.sh"
# SetEnv ELASTIC5 %{elastic_cookies}e
```

My goal is to call **get_cookies.sh** script and the output -> **some_long_cookie_string** will be set dynamically with every call on apache.

Any ideas ??????????????

Answer (score 0):

The answer how to use variable in Apache 2.4 configuration is pasted below
Detailed explanation can be found at this blog
https://linuxinuse.com/devopsblog , https://linuxinuse.com/devopsblog/make-heartbeat-5-use-ssocookies-authentication-method-leveraging-apache-2-4-proxy-dynamically-loaded-ssocookies-variable/

```
Listen 8000
...
SSLProxyEngine on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap elastic_cookies "txt:/opt/apache/httpd_2.4/up_to_date_cookie.txt"
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=ELASTIC5:${elastic_cookies:my_cookies},P]
RequestHeader set Cookie "SSOLogin=badcookie; SSOCookie=%{ELASTIC5}e"
ProxyPass /end_point http://www.endpoint.com
ProxyPassReverse /end_point http://www.endpoint.com
ProxyPass /other_end_point http://www.other_end_point.com
ProxyPassReverse /other_end_point http://www.other_end_point.com
</VirtualHost>
```